# How to get referrer page when there's a redirect after access denied?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

Whenever a user with insufficient privileges tries to access a page I redirect him to the login page by setting the `access_denied_url` to `/login` field in my `security.yml`

My security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
    access_denied_url: /login

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: ~
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/tc, role: ROLE_TC }
        - { path: ^/operations, role: ROLE_OPERATIONS }
```

In my twig template I want to get the page the user tried to access so how can I do that?

I've tried to get the target path and the referer path as follows but both of them are empty

```
app.session.get('_security.secured_area.target_path')
app.request.headers.get('referer')
```

Comment: try to have redirect url in session before redirect

Comment: Could you please tell me how? @Farhan

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879164/symfony2-using-referer-after-login-with-fosuserbundle

Comment: I think `_security.secured_area.target_path` is the right session variable to use. Can you see it in the profiler for the login page?

Comment: Are you using a custom exception listener, which prevents the Symfony security component listener from setting the target path? Check the `ExceptionListener::setTargetPath()` method is actually running on authentication failure. See https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `use_referer`.

This is my `security.yml` file:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                use_referer: true
            logout:    true
            anonymous: true
```

Comment: `use_referer` isn't normally needed to send the user back to the failed page. The default authentication exception listener puts the blocked URL into the session.

Comment: @Ryan , I had to set this to true. The documentation says it's the dafault behavior, but in practice, without this setting, the user is redirected to the home page.

Comment: I suspect that is an issue relating to storing the target path in the session. The setting does typically work as described.